# Could not get offline access token using Ms documentation Skydrive

Tags: onedrive

I want to integrate SkyDrive with single sign on in which users has to sign in and give consent only once in our website. After that they can access their SkyDrive files/folders to upload seamlessly.
I have created my application and did all app settings as mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659751.aspx.
I followed sample in link https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/tree/master/src/Web/Samples/OAuthServer/Asp.net/OAuthSample 
But I am getting 400 error bad request when I use REST API to get access token and refresh token.
can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a Redirect Url issue. Can you check to see if the Redirect Url that you're using is the same in the following 2 places:

1. When you created the app (in your app settings page -
   https://account.live.com/developers/applications/summary/YOUR_APP_ID)
2. The redirectUrl passed as parameter in your REST API call. (GET
   https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=SCOPES&response_type=RESPONSE_TYPE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL)

Comment: Hi thank you for helping out. I found that code returned from onedrive should be processed immediately within 30secs to get access token. I have resolved it now. Thank you.